# Is it safe to chain together functions that assign a value by pointer and return a success code using the || operator?

Tags: c++

When dealing with functions that have a signature like:

```
bool getValue(int parameter, int *out)
```

where they write their result to the memory addressed by `*out` and return a boolean indicating whether the function succeeded, I'm considering using the following pattern to chain several of these functions together in an order of priority:

```
int result = 0;
bool success = getValue(param1, &result) || getValue(param2, &result) ||
               getAnotherValue(param3, &result);

if (success) {
    // do something with result
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

I'm thinking it would be a more succinct and pretty version of this:

```
int result = 0;
bool success = getValue(param1, &result);

if (!success) {
    success = getValue(param2, &result);

    if (!success) {
        success = getAnotherValue(param3, &result);
    }
}

if (success) {
    // do something with result
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

As I understand, if any one of the functions succeed then the `||` operator will short circuit and the remaining functions won't be called, leaving the desired output in `result`.

Is this a safe pattern to use, especially in code that is cross-platform and will be compiled using different compilers (e.g. clang, gcc, and msvc?)

Comment: Surely you mean `if (success)` but other than that your code is fine, in fact I'd say perfectly common.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "safe"? What is your desired outcome? Are you concerned about interleaving? Evaluation order? What?

Comment: So basically, you're asking if short circuiting is guaranteed, right?

Comment: If there's a user overloaded `operator||` involved, that one wouldn't short circuit.  Since these are all `bool`, the short-circuiting behavior is required by the standard and can be relied upon.  (General _best practices_ guidance recommends never defining your own `operator||`.)

Comment: @john Yes, quite right! I managed to miss that after proof reading my question three times.

Comment: Am I crazy or do you mean `&&` instead of `||`? If the first `getValue` returns `true`, then the whole `||` thing is `true` and the second call doesn't happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's what he wants.

Comment: @john Then `if (!success)` was correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm having a hard time using my brain today apparently, in spite of my efforts to be clear in my question.

Comment: It's actually a good example of how the `||` is clearer and easier to get your head around, than the chain of negated `if` statements. And with `||=` it doesn't have to be in one statement either.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The code in the current question is correct, but the earlier code had more instances of `if (!success)` and was not correct going by the comments.

Comment: @john So, you were actually intending to refer solely to the final `if`, but the OP misunderstood and changed them all? Okay

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings He hasn't changed them all, at least not in the code I'm looking at.

Comment: Originally line 12 in my second code blurb was erroneously `if (!success) {`. I then incorrectly changed all of the instances of `if (!success) {` to `if (success) {`, then realized my mistake and changed it to its current correct state. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @john Yes, that's because I pointed out the mistake you triggered. :P Look at the question's revision history.

Comment: @GuyGizmo No worries, I could have been more specific in my original comment. This is getting boring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second piece of code is assuredly equivalent to the first piece of code, if that's what you're asking.

Short-circuiting means the "unused" expressions on the right of a non-overloaded `||` aren't evaluated, which means the functions aren't called, which means `&result` isn't touched again.

Any compiler not abiding by these semantics is not just flagrantly non-compliant to the C++ standard, but unheard of.

However, *this is not the case for an overloaded `||`*. As a result, we're encouraged not to make any.

Comment: Yes that is essentially what I'm asking, but I'm also interested in all of the edge cases that particular pattern could have given C++'s ability to override operators or cause side effects.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying, in spite of my original post's and edit's errors. Regarding overloaded `||`, will that only prevent short-circuiting if the returned types have an overloaded `||`, or could a different type's overloaded `||` also prevent short-circuiting?

Comment: @GuyGizmo There is only one way to overload the operator, and that is by doing so in terms of the operands you give it - in this case, that's the return types of your functions.